# Aligning [public-key] and [privatekey]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

There's [public-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/public-key), and [privatekey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privatekey), which are the opposite ends of the same concept.

We should either consider merging both, as they're pretty much relevant together all the time, maybe even including [public-key-encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/public-key-encryption).

In any case, we should align both to preferably [public-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/public-key) and [private-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/private-key).

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're asking this? At the moment (to me at least) it comes across as saying let's make "true and false map to boolean"?

Comment: Very often, those three tags are used randomly and together. For a programming point of view, the concept of public-key-encryption is relevant. Public and private keys _always_ occur in pairs. The tags are just to specific for Stack Overflow, there is no reasonable distinction on how they're used.

Comment: Although I do not quite agree to analogy, given we'd have [true] and [false], we should indeed consider mapping true and false to boolean, to match the concept instead of instances. It makes sense speaking about booleans, it does make very limited sense to speak about falses. Or trues.

Comment: On the first page of 50 questions tagged [tag:public-key-encryption], only 4 questions had either [tag:public-key] or [tag:privatekey] as well, and none had both. There were a lot of [tag:encryption] tags to go along with them.  There are about 500 questions tagged [tag:public-key], about 700 tagged [tag:privatekey] and about 900 tagged [tag:public-key-encryption].  I'm not sure what this says about anything.  Changing the spelling so it is systematic is clearly a good idea, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[privatekey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privatekey) is now a synonym for and has been merged into [private-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/private-key).

I copied/pasted the tag excerpt from the old tag for the new one but from a glance it could do with a review and edit if anyone feels up for it.

Comment: Revised the excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments against merging [private-key] into [public-key-encryption]:

- The two other big parts where public and private keys are used are signatures ([digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature)) and key exchange ([diffie-hellman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diffie-hellman)). Merging private keys into of those is certainly not the right thing to do.
- There are questions about encoding and decoding private keys that have nothing to do with the encryption aspect or with the corresponding public key.